# White block in web page background on Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 developing a website.

Chrome does not render the background correctly. The bottom renders fine, which is the footer that covers the entire width. However the background of the content div is just white.

See the image for reference (*I'm new to Stackoverflow and need more rep to post images*):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqnlg9eh4k7cbv5/white-background-os.png?dl=0

The problem does not occur on OS X or Windows, and the choice of browser does not affect the problem.

I'm using a Alienware M14X R2, so I thought that maybe the Nvidia drivers could be the problem but they are up to date.

Code for the background:

It only happens on this particular site, so I'm guessing something's wrong with my CSS. What's so weird is that it's just with Ubuntu (and I'm guessing several other Linux distributions as well)

Basically I have this:

HTML (homepage.ejs)

```
<div ui-view ng-app="myApp" id="wrap-content">
   <!--Content swapped with Angular and ui-router-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  html {
    background: url("images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  div#wrap-content {
    width: 900px;
    height: 84vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 45px;
  }
... a bunch of other stuff
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thats a bit strange, are you on the latest version of chrome ? Welcome to SO BTW, does this happen on other sites or just locally ?

Comment: Would be helpful to see more css around this. If the bg is on the html, then it's centered over the entire document, so if you had more stuff below, ie the document is longer than the screen, this code would be producing the correct results.

Comment: I just updated my question with some more HTML, I don't really know what might be causing the problem so if you want more just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just solved this by accident. Applying the background to HTML caused this weird problem. Changing it to:

```
body {
    background: url("images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Solved the issue. Hope this can be useful to anyone ever having the same problem!